# Get field content from tid

Tags: entities, nodes

I am wondering how to retrieve the actual data of a field instead of the tid on a node.
Googling around I found a solution to a similar problem, by constructing a query on my own. However, it is usually the case that a function already exists for this. Do you know how I can achieve this?

What I get is something like this

```
field_category (Array, 1 element)
  -> und (Array, 1 element)
    -> 0 (Array, 1 element)
      -> tid (String, 2 characters ) 18
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically for taxonomy terms you have [`taxonomy_term_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7), e.g.

```
if ($field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_category')) {
  $tid = $field_items[0]['tid'];
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
}
```

Comment: I've also found quite useful the field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_category');